# filter, map, sort and concat

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, concatenation

I feel there could be a better solution because I've duplicate code in following routine (map and sort).

It's an arbitrary list of messages with read (1 or null) and unread status (0). I'm displaying unread messages on the top while read messages on the bottom with some sorting and mapping applied and then at the end concatenating both results.

```
var unread = data.filter(function(item){
    return item.Read == 0;
}).map(function(item){
    return {Id: item.Id, First: item.First.toLowerCase(), Last: item.Last.toLowerCase()}
}).sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.Last < b.Last) return -1;
    if (a.Last > b.Last) return 1;
    return 0;
});

var read = data.filter(function(item){
    return item.Read == null || item.Read == 1;
}).map(function(item){ // lowercase (first, last) and sort the list by last
    return {Id: item.Id, First: item.First.toLowerCase(), Last: item.Last.toLowerCase()}
}).sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.Last < b.Last) return -1;
    if (a.Last > b.Last) return 1;
    return 0;
});

var finalData = unread.concat(read);
```

**Edit**

```
var input = [
    {Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "B", Read:0},
    {Id: 1, First: "Jane", Last: "C", Read:0},
    {Id: 1, First: "Doe", Last: "D", Read:1},
    {Id: 1, First: "Alpha", Last: "B", Read:1},
    {Id: 1, First: "Beta", Last: "C", Read:null},
    ];

var output = [
    {Id: 1, First: "Alpha", Last: "B", Read:1},
    {Id: 1, First: "Doe", Last: "D", Read:1},
    {Id: 1, First: "Beta", Last: "C", Read: null},
    {Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "B", Read:0}
    {Id: 1, First: "Jane", Last: "C", Read:0},
];
```

Comment: Add input and expected output to your question.

Comment: edited with some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just want to sort on multiple fields. To sort first by read status, then by last name and then by first name (ignoring case), you can just:

```js
var data = [
  {Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "B", Read:0},
  {Id: 1, First: "Jane", Last: "C", Read:0},
  {Id: 1, First: "Doe", Last: "D", Read:1},
  {Id: 1, First: "Alpha", Last: "B", Read:1}
];

data.sort((a, b) =>
  b.Read !== a.Read
    ? b.Read - a.Read
    : a.Last.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Last.toLowerCase())
      ? a.Last.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Last.toLowerCase())
      : a.First.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.First.toLowerCase()));
    
console.log(data);
```

**Update**

To deal with the fact that `null` values for the `Read` field are (counterintuitively) considered to be *truthy*, you'd have to introduce a couple of temporary variables (`let aRead = a.Read != null a.Read : 1`) and compare those, or rewrite the comparison as follows:

```js
var data = [
  {Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "B", Read:0},
  {Id: 1, First: "Jane", Last: "C", Read:0},
  {Id: 1, First: "Doe", Last: "D", Read:1},
  {Id: 1, First: "Alpha", Last: "B", Read:1},
  {Id: 1, First: "Beta", Last: "C", Read:null}
];

data.sort((a, b) =>
  b.Read !== a.Read
    ? (b.Read != null ? b.Read : 1) - (a.Read != null ? a.Read : 1)
    : a.Last.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Last.toLowerCase())
      ? a.Last.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Last.toLowerCase())
      : a.First.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.First.toLowerCase()));
    
console.log(data);
```

Comment: it's sorting and then grouping based on the read status (concat), see my answer to get an idea or any improvements. Unread messages go to the top (alphabetical by last name) and the rest go to the bottom (also alphabetical)

Comment: @Devyiweid There's no need for grouping, filtering or concatenating. You can just treat everything is a sort. My output matches your expected output.

Comment: thanks Robby for the insight that it's basically a sorting in essence, I've a bit of issue with `Read:null` records, added to my inputs, please advise again.

Comment: @Devyiweid Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `map` and `sort` functions into their own named functions and reuse them:

```
// helpers
function processItem(item) {
    return {Id: item.Id, First: item.First.toLowerCase(), Last: item.Last.toLowerCase()}
}

function sortItemByLast(a, b) {
    if (a.Last < b.Last) return -1;
    if (a.Last > b.Last) return 1;
    return 0;
};

// process data
var unread = data.filter(function(item){
    return item.Read == 0;
}).map(processItem).sort(sortItemByLast);

var read = data.filter(function(item){
    return item.Read == null || item.Read == 1;
}).map(processItem).sort(sortItemByLast);


var finalData = unread.concat(read);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` first, then use `reduce` to accumulate the result:

```js
var data = [
    {Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "B", Read:0},
    {Id: 1, First: "Jane", Last: "C", Read:0},
    {Id: 1, First: "Doe", Last: "D", Read:1},
    {Id: 1, First: "Alpha", Last: "B", Read:1}
];

var result = data.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.Last < b.Last) return -1;
    if (a.Last > b.Last) return 1;
    return 0;
}).reduce(function(res, o) {
    var newO = {Id: o.Id, First: o.First.toLowerCase(), Last: o.Last.toLowerCase()}; // the object to be pushed to either the read or unread array (if you are not using the old object o, then just remove the property "Read" from it and use it without creating a new object)
    res[o.Read == 0? "unread": "read"].push(newO);  // push o to either the read or unread array, depending on the property "Read"
    return res;
}, {read: [], unread: []});                         // the initiale value will be an object containing two arrays (one for read and one for unread objects)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please have the labels (read/unread) removed, see my output. Possible?thanks

Comment: please also see my answer for any improvements

Comment: @Devyiweid It's not that difficult. The object is containg the two arrays. See the new edit.

Comment: @KikoGarcia Why?

Comment: @Devyiweid Sorry! I misunderstood. `Read` property is removed. Read the comments for more emprovement as I think creating a new object is not necessary.